# Before the AZ Tech asset led Inc aqua group

Tags: riddle, history

Clarifying that this puzzle is looking for a hidden civilization - the title also contains clues alluding to something similar.

Guy Fawkes slept

on April Fools day

and dreamt of American

or Texan Independence

for all saints.


Hint:

> Dates can lead to a civilized answer.

Comment: Possibly a valid question: Are the clues to be figured out in a US way or rest of world way? (If this question doesn't make sense then I'm way off so ignore)

Comment: @SlashmanX - Fair question and US/World format doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: Guy Fawkes is Nov-5. April Fools is Apr-1. American Independence=Jul-4. Texan Independence=Mar-2. All Saints=Nov-1.

Comment: @Van.Graaf Correct start. The answer can be found from these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Van Graaf for listing the dates, I would have some trouble identifying American holidays.

You're looking for

> the Maya civilization.

Reasoning:

> Take the letter in the month name corresponding to the dates:
>
>  Guy Fawkes is Nov-5: Nove**m**ber
>  April Fools is Apr-1: **A**pril
>  American Independence=Jul-4: Jul**y**
>  Texan Independence=Mar-2: M**a**rch
>  All Saints=Nov-1: **N**ovember
>
>  Together, the letters form the word "mayan".

Comment: The title has two other American civilizations hidden in it: Aztec and Inca.